# Onsuccess backend request handler not working as expected by calling a successful action when order is paid

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, paystack

I have been trying to get a success handling function to work for days but with no progress. This function is suppose to make a put request to the backend and set order.isPaid to true when customer successfull pays with card which will then activate a box in the frontend to green to show a customer that the payment was successful whenever they come to that page. I first used Paypal as the payment method which worked pretty fine but had to change to Paystack payment method as Paypal doesn't work in my country but since I made the changes, I began having the problem. Perhaps theres a way to fix this and hopefully someone will help me soon. Below are the respective codes for your reference.

**Backend**

routes/orderRoutes.js

```
import express from 'express';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import Order from '../models/orderModel.js';
import User from '../models/userModel.js';
import Product from '../models/productModel.js';
import { isAuth, isAdmin, mailgun, payOrderEmailTemplate } from '../utils.js';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const orderRouter = express.Router();

orderRouter.put(
  '/:id/pay',
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id).populate(
      'user',
      'email name'
    );
    if (order) {
      
      order.isPaid = true;
      order.paidAt = Date.now();
      order.paymentResult = {
        id: req.body.id,
        status: req.body.status,
        update_time: req.body.update_time,
        email_address: req.body.email_address,
      };

      const updatedOrder = await order.save();
      res.send({ message: 'Order Paid', order: updatedOrder });
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: 'Order Not Found' });
    }
  })
);
```

**Frontend**
src/screens/OrderScreen.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import { Store } from '../Store';
import { getError, API_URL } from '../utils';
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { usePaystackPayment } from 'react-paystack';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: '' };
    case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loading: false, order: action.payload, error: '' };
    case 'FETCH_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case 'PAY_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: true };
    case 'PAY_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: false, successPay: true };
    case 'PAY_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: false, errorPay: action.payload };
    case 'PAY_RESET':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: false, successPay: false };
    case 'DELIVER_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loadingDeliver: true };
    case 'DELIVER_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loadingDeliver: false, successDeliver: true };
    case 'DELIVER_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loadingDeliver: false };
    case 'DELIVER_RESET':
      return {
        ...state,
        loadingDeliver: false,
        successDeliver: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default function OrderScreen() {
  const { state } = useContext(Store);
  const { userInfo } = state;
  const params = useParams();
  const { id: orderId } = params;
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [
    {
      loading,
      error,
      order,
      successPay,
      loadingPay,
      loadingDeliver,
      successDeliver,
    },
    dispatch,
  ] = useReducer(reducer, {
    loading: true,
    order: {},
    error: '',
    successPay: false,
    loadingPay: false,
  });

  function onSuccess() {
    return async function () {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_REQUEST' });
        const { data } = await axios.put(
          `${API_URL}/api/order/${orderId}/pay`,

          {
            headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
          }
        );
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_SUCCESS', payload: data });
        toast.success('Order is paid');
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_FAIL', payload: getError(err) });
        toast.error(getError(err));
      }
    };
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOrder = async () => {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_REQUEST' });
        const { data } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/orders/${orderId}`, {
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        });
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: data });
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAIL', payload: getError(err) });
      }
    };
    if (!userInfo) {
      return navigate('/login');
    }
    if (
      !order._id ||
      successPay ||
      successDeliver ||
      (order._id && order._id !== orderId)
    ) {
      fetchOrder();
      if (successPay) {
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_RESET' });
      }
      if (successDeliver) {
        dispatch({ type: 'DELIVER_RESET' });
      }
    }
  }, [order, userInfo, orderId, navigate, successPay, successDeliver]);

  async function deliverOrderHandler() {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: 'DELIVER_REQUEST' });
      const { data } = await axios.put(
        `${API_URL}/api/orders/${order._id}/deliver`,
        {},
        {
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        }
      );
      dispatch({ type: 'DELIVER_SUCCESS', payload: data });
      toast.success('Order is delivered');
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error(getError(err));
      dispatch({ type: 'DELIVER_FAIL' });
    }
  }

  const onClose = () => {
    // implementation for  whatever you want to do when the Paystack dialog closed.
    console.log('closed');
  };

  const config = {
    reference: new Date().getTime().toString(),
    email: userInfo.email,
    amount: order.totalPrice * 100, //Amount is in the country's lowest currency. E.g Kobo, so 20000 kobo = N200
    publicKey: 'pk_test',
  };

  const PaystackHookExample = () => {
    const initializePayment = usePaystackPayment(config);
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            initializePayment(onClose, onSuccess);
          }}
        >
          Make Payment
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return loading ? (
    <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
  ) : error ? (
    <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Order {orderId}</title>
      </Helmet>
      <h1 className="my-3">Order {orderId}</h1>
      <Row>
        <Col md={8}>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Shipping</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                <strong>Name:</strong> {order.shippingAddress.fullName} <br />
                <strong>Address: </strong> {order.shippingAddress.address},
                {order.shippingAddress.city}, {order.shippingAddress.postalCode}
                ,{order.shippingAddress.country}
                &nbsp;
                {order.shippingAddress.location &&
                  order.shippingAddress.location.lat && (
                    <a
                      target="_new"
                      href={`https://maps.google.com?q=${order.shippingAddress.location.lat},${order.shippingAddress.location.lng}`}
                    >
                      Show On Map
                    </a>
                  )}
              </Card.Text>
              {order.isDelivered ? (
                <MessageBox variant="success">
                  Delivered at {order.deliveredAt}
                </MessageBox>
              ) : (
                <MessageBox variant="danger">Not Delivered</MessageBox>
              )}
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Payment</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                <strong>Method:</strong> {order.paymentMethod}
              </Card.Text>
              {order.isPaid ? (
                <MessageBox variant="success">
                  Paid at {order.paidAt}
                </MessageBox>
              ) : (
                <MessageBox variant="danger">Not Paid</MessageBox>
              )}
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>

          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Items</Card.Title>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                {order.orderItems?.map((item) => (
                  <ListGroup.Item key={item._id}>
                    <Row className="align-items-center">
                      <Col md={6}>
                        <img
                          src={item.image}
                          alt={item.name}
                          className="img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail"
                        ></img>{' '}
                        <Link to={`/product/${item.slug}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                      </Col>
                      <Col md={3}>
                        <span>{item.quantity}</span>
                      </Col>
                      <Col md={3}>₦{item.price}</Col>
                    </Row>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                ))}
              </ListGroup>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col md={4}>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Order Summary</Card.Title>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Items</Col>
                    <Col>₦{order.itemsPrice.toFixed(2)}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Shipping</Col>
                    <Col>₦{order.shippingPrice.toFixed(2)}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Tax</Col>
                    <Col>₦{order.taxPrice.toFixed(2)}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>
                      <strong> Order Total</strong>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                      <strong>₦{order.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}</strong>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                {!order.isPaid && (
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    <div>
                      <PaystackHookExample />
                    </div>
                    {loadingPay && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                )}
                {userInfo.isAdmin && order.isPaid && !order.isDelivered && (
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    {loadingDeliver && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
                    <div className="d-grid">
                      <Button type="button" onClick={deliverOrderHandler}>
                        Deliver Order
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                )}
              </ListGroup>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This following code is what worked when I was using PayPal before the changes I made as showed above.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import { PayPalButtons, usePayPalScriptReducer } from '@paypal/react-paypal-js';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import { Store } from '../Store';
import { getError, API_URL } from '../utils';
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: '' };
    case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loading: false, order: action.payload, error: '' };
    case 'FETCH_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case 'PAY_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: true };
    case 'PAY_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: false, successPay: true };
    case 'PAY_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: false, errorPay: action.payload };
    case 'PAY_RESET':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: false, successPay: false };
    case 'DELIVER_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loadingDeliver: true };
    case 'DELIVER_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loadingDeliver: false, successDeliver: true };
    case 'DELIVER_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loadingDeliver: false };
    case 'DELIVER_RESET':
      return {
        ...state,
        loadingDeliver: false,
        successDeliver: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default function OrderScreen() {
  const { state } = useContext(Store);
  const { userInfo } = state;
  const params = useParams();
  const { id: orderId } = params;
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [
    {
      loading,
      error,
      order,
      successPay,
      loadingPay,
      loadingDeliver,
      successDeliver,
    },
    dispatch,
  ] = useReducer(reducer, {
    loading: true,
    order: {},
    error: '',
    successPay: false,
    loadingPay: false,
  });

  const [{ isPending }, paypalDispatch] = usePayPalScriptReducer();

  function createOrder(data, actions) {
    return actions.order
      .create({
        purchase_units: [
          {
            amount: { value: order.totalPrice },
          },
        ],
      })
      .then((orderID) => {
        return orderID;
      });
  }

  function onApprove(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.capture().then(async function (details) {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_REQUEST' });
        const { data } = await axios.put(
          `${API_URL}/api/orders/${order._id}/pay`,
          details,
          {
            headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
          }
        );
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_SUCCESS', payload: data });
        toast.success('Order is paid');
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_FAIL', payload: getError(err) });
        toast.error(getError(err));
      }
    });
  }

  function onError(err) {
    toast.error(getError(err));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOrder = async () => {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_REQUEST' });
        const { data } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/orders/${orderId}`, {
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        });
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: data });
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAIL', payload: getError(err) });
      }
    };
    if (!userInfo) {
      return navigate('/login');
    }
    if (
      !order._id ||
      successPay ||
      successDeliver ||
      (order._id && order._id !== orderId)
    ) {
      fetchOrder();
      if (successPay) {
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_RESET' });
      }
      if (successDeliver) {
        dispatch({ type: 'DELIVER_RESET' });
      }
    } else {
      const loadPayPalScript = async () => {
        const { data: clientId } = await axios.get(
          `${API_URL}/api/keys/paypal`,
          {
            headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
          }
        );
        paypalDispatch({
          type: 'resetOptions',
          value: {
            'client-id': clientId,
            currency: 'NGN',
          },
        });
        paypalDispatch({ type: 'setLoadingStatus', value: 'pending' });
      };
      loadPayPalScript();
    }
  }, [
    order,
    userInfo,
    orderId,
    navigate,
    paypalDispatch,
    successPay,
    successDeliver,
  ]);

  async function deliverOrderHandler() {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: 'DELIVER_REQUEST' });
      const { data } = await axios.put(
        `${API_URL}/api/orders/${order._id}/deliver`,
        {},
        {
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        }
      );
      dispatch({ type: 'DELIVER_SUCCESS', payload: data });
      toast.success('Order is delivered');
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error(getError(err));
      dispatch({ type: 'DELIVER_FAIL' });
    }
  }

  return loading ? (
    <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
  ) : error ? (
    <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Order {orderId}</title>
      </Helmet>
      <h1 className="my-3">Order {orderId}</h1>
      <Row>
        <Col md={8}>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Shipping</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                <strong>Name:</strong> {order.shippingAddress.fullName} <br />
                <strong>Address: </strong> {order.shippingAddress.address},
                {order.shippingAddress.city}, {order.shippingAddress.postalCode}
                ,{order.shippingAddress.country}
                &nbsp;
                {order.shippingAddress.location &&
                  order.shippingAddress.location.lat && (
                    <a
                      target="_new"
                      href={`https://maps.google.com?q=${order.shippingAddress.location.lat},${order.shippingAddress.location.lng}`}
                    >
                      Show On Map
                    </a>
                  )}
              </Card.Text>
              {order.isDelivered ? (
                <MessageBox variant="success">
                  Delivered at {order.deliveredAt}
                </MessageBox>
              ) : (
                <MessageBox variant="danger">Not Delivered</MessageBox>
              )}
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Payment</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                <strong>Method:</strong> {order.paymentMethod}
              </Card.Text>
              {order.isPaid ? (
                <MessageBox variant="success">
                  Paid at {order.paidAt}
                </MessageBox>
              ) : (
                <MessageBox variant="danger">Not Paid</MessageBox>
              )}
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>

          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Items</Card.Title>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                {order.orderItems?.map((item) => (
                  <ListGroup.Item key={item._id}>
                    <Row className="align-items-center">
                      <Col md={6}>
                        <img
                          src={item.image}
                          alt={item.name}
                          className="img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail"
                        ></img>{' '}
                        <Link to={`/product/${item.slug}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                      </Col>
                      <Col md={3}>
                        <span>{item.quantity}</span>
                      </Col>
                      <Col md={3}>₦{item.price}</Col>
                    </Row>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                ))}
              </ListGroup>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col md={4}>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Order Summary</Card.Title>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Items</Col>
                    <Col>₦{order.itemsPrice.toFixed(2)}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Shipping</Col>
                    <Col>₦{order.shippingPrice.toFixed(2)}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Tax</Col>
                    <Col>₦{order.taxPrice.toFixed(2)}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>
                      <strong> Order Total</strong>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                      <strong>₦{order.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}</strong>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                {!order.isPaid && (
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    {isPending ? (
                      <LoadingBox />
                    ) : (
                      <div>
                        <PayPalButtons
                          createOrder={createOrder}
                          onApprove={onApprove}
                          onError={onError}
                        ></PayPalButtons>
                      </div>
                    )}
                    {loadingPay && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                )}
                {userInfo.isAdmin && order.isPaid && !order.isDelivered && (
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    {loadingDeliver && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
                    <div className="d-grid">
                      <Button type="button" onClick={deliverOrderHandler}>
                        Deliver Order
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                )}
              </ListGroup>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply replaced the OrderScreen.js with following code below

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import { Store } from '../Store';
import { getError, API_URL } from '../utils';
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { PaystackButton } from 'react-paystack';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: '' };
    case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loading: false, order: action.payload, error: '' };
    case 'FETCH_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case 'PAY_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: true };
    case 'PAY_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: false, successPay: true };
    case 'PAY_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: false, errorPay: action.payload };
    case 'PAY_RESET':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: false, successPay: false };
    case 'DELIVER_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loadingDeliver: true };
    case 'DELIVER_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loadingDeliver: false, successDeliver: true };
    case 'DELIVER_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loadingDeliver: false };
    case 'DELIVER_RESET':
      return {
        ...state,
        loadingDeliver: false,
        successDeliver: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default function OrderScreen() {
  const { state } = useContext(Store);
  const { userInfo } = state;
  const params = useParams();
  const { id: orderId } = params;
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [
    {
      loading,
      error,
      order,
      successPay,
      loadingPay,
      loadingDeliver,
      successDeliver,
    },
    dispatch,
  ] = useReducer(reducer, {
    loading: true,
    order: {},
    error: '',
    successPay: false,
    loadingPay: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOrder = async () => {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_REQUEST' });
        const { data } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/orders/${orderId}`, {
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        });
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: data });
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAIL', payload: getError(err) });
      }
    };
    if (!userInfo) {
      return navigate('/login');
    }
    if (
      !order._id ||
      successPay ||
      successDeliver ||
      (order._id && order._id !== orderId)
    ) {
      fetchOrder();
      if (successPay) {
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_RESET' });
      }
      if (successDeliver) {
        dispatch({ type: 'DELIVER_RESET' });
      }
    }
  }, [order, userInfo, orderId, navigate, successPay, successDeliver]);

  async function deliverOrderHandler() {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: 'DELIVER_REQUEST' });
      const { data } = await axios.put(
        `${API_URL}/api/orders/${order._id}/deliver`,
        {},
        {
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        }
      );
      dispatch({ type: 'DELIVER_SUCCESS', payload: data });
      toast.success('Order is delivered');
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error(getError(err));
      dispatch({ type: 'DELIVER_FAIL' });
    }
  }

  const componentProps = {
    reference: new Date().getTime().toString(),
    email: userInfo.email,
    amount: order.totalPrice * 100, //Amount is in the country's lowest currency. E.g Kobo, so 20000 kobo = N200
    publicKey: 'pk_test_250cf555c853c1c4f4d8bbad93f8d3dfa7f37b33',
    text: 'Pay Now',
    onSuccess: () => {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_REQUEST' });
        const { data } = axios.put(
          `${API_URL}/api/orders/${order._id}/pay`,
          order,
          {
            headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
          }
        );
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_SUCCESS', payload: data });
        toast.success('Order is paid');
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_FAIL', payload: getError(err) });
        toast.error(getError(err));
      }
    },

    // alert('Thanks for doing business with us! Come back soon!!'),
    onClose: () => alert("Wait! You need this oil, don't go!!!!"),
  };

  return loading ? (
    <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
  ) : error ? (
    <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Order {orderId}</title>
      </Helmet>
      <h1 className="my-3">Order {orderId}</h1>
      <Row>
        <Col md={8}>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Shipping</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                <strong>Name:</strong> {order.shippingAddress.fullName} <br />
                <strong>Address: </strong> {order.shippingAddress.address},
                {order.shippingAddress.city}, {order.shippingAddress.postalCode}
                ,{order.shippingAddress.country}
                &nbsp;
                {order.shippingAddress.location &&
                  order.shippingAddress.location.lat && (
                    <a
                      target="_new"
                      href={`https://maps.google.com?q=${order.shippingAddress.location.lat},${order.shippingAddress.location.lng}`}
                    >
                      Show On Map
                    </a>
                  )}
              </Card.Text>
              {order.isDelivered ? (
                <MessageBox variant="success">
                  Delivered at {order.deliveredAt}
                </MessageBox>
              ) : (
                <MessageBox variant="danger">Not Delivered</MessageBox>
              )}
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Payment</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                <strong>Method:</strong> {order.paymentMethod}
              </Card.Text>
              {order.isPaid ? (
                <MessageBox variant="success">
                  Paid at {order.paidAt}
                </MessageBox>
              ) : (
                <MessageBox variant="danger">Not Paid</MessageBox>
              )}
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>

          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Items</Card.Title>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                {order.orderItems?.map((item) => (
                  <ListGroup.Item key={item._id}>
                    <Row className="align-items-center">
                      <Col md={6}>
                        <img
                          src={item.image}
                          alt={item.name}
                          className="img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail"
                        ></img>{' '}
                        <Link to={`/product/${item.slug}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                      </Col>
                      <Col md={3}>
                        <span>{item.quantity}</span>
                      </Col>
                      <Col md={3}>₦{item.price}</Col>
                    </Row>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                ))}
              </ListGroup>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col md={4}>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Order Summary</Card.Title>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Items</Col>
                    <Col>₦{order.itemsPrice.toFixed(2)}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Shipping</Col>
                    <Col>₦{order.shippingPrice.toFixed(2)}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Tax</Col>
                    <Col>₦{order.taxPrice.toFixed(2)}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>
                      <strong> Order Total</strong>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                      <strong>₦{order.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}</strong>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                {!order.isPaid && (
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    <div>
                      <PaystackButton
                        {...componentProps}
                        className="paystack-button"
                      />{' '}
                    </div>
                    {loadingPay && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                )}
                {userInfo.isAdmin && order.isPaid && !order.isDelivered && (
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    {loadingDeliver && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
                    <div className="d-grid">
                      <Button type="button" onClick={deliverOrderHandler}>
                        Deliver Order
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                )}
              </ListGroup>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
```